# drawing html with the right, fit image inside

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a box and contain image and title like the one showing in this site http://injo.com/  [image]

see under More News, those boxes. I tried looking into their source code, and tried to do it on my own but got stuck. So here's what I did,

```
<div class="row">
  {% for news in newsInCat %}
    <div class='col-sm-4'>
      <div class="card">
    <a href='{{ news.get_absolute_url }}'>
    <div class="card-image"><img src='{{news.get_image_url}}' height:'4px;' width:'4px;'/></div>
    <div class="content">{{ news.title }}</div></a>
    </div>
    </div>  
  {% endfor %}    
</div>
```

{% %} are django template language, I'm using for loop to loop my cotents through. Lastly, if anyone can teach me how to insert text such as More News in hr,I would really appreciate your help. thank you

Comment: What is your *specific* question?

Comment: @Roy how do I create the box like the pic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you only need the image to be as wide as the container it's in. Something like this will get you started.

```css
.col-sm-4 {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  flex-basis: calc(100%/3);
  border: 1px solid pink;
  margin: 3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-image {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.content h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <div class="card">
      <a href='#'>
        <div class="card-image"><img src='http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg'/></div>
        <div class="content">
           <h1>This is a news title</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, quam.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <a href='#'>
        <div class="card-image"><img src='http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg'/></div>
        <div class="content">
           <h1>This is a news title</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, quam.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <a href='#'>
        <div class="card-image"><img src='http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg'/></div>
        <div class="content">
           <h1>This is a news title</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, quam.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: hello, thank you very much.can you please help me with this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860840/how-to-fit-image-into-the-carousel-carousel-is-working-fine-just-having-some-t I've been trying to do this for hours but just can't figure it out

Comment: hello, and I tried your code but it looks like this;http://imgur.com/7HN4muT I have six boxes but as you see top and bottom are too close together, and the contents in the box are too far from the image in the box. can you please help me with this

Comment: Change the height of the `.card` to get the desired height. Also add some `margin` around it. I just edited my answer.

Comment: thank you but if I decrease the heigh of .card and padding then the whole thing gets out of the box....

Comment: See my edited version again. I removed the `height` on the image and the `height` on `.card`. Therefore it will get the height of its content.